# how to get list of files from a directory into text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This question is how to get list of files from a directory into text file using python.

Result in the text file should exactly be like this:

```
E:\AA\a.jpg
E:\AA\b.jpg
...
```

How to correct the code below:

```
WD = "E:\\AA"
import glob
files = glob.glob ('*.jpg')
with open ('infiles.txt', 'w') as in_files:
    in_files.write(files +'\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

`glob.glob()` returns a list. You have to iterate through it.

```
WD = "E:\\AA"
import glob
files = glob.glob ('*.jpg')
with open ('infiles.txt', 'w') as in_files:
    for eachfile in files: in_files.write(eachfile+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

- Input directory path : WD = "E://AA"
- You can assign specific file extention that you needed eg: path = WD+'/*.jpg',
- if you need all file list then give '*' eg: path = WD+'/*'

  `import glob
  w_dir = WD + "/*.jpg"
  with open("infiles.txt","wb")as fp:
      for path in [filepath for filepath in glob.glob(w_dir)]:
          fp.write(path+"\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Without path, glob.glob returns list of filename (No directory part). To get full path you need to call `os.path.abspath(filename)` / `os.path.realpath(filename)` / `os.path.join(WD, filename)`

```
>>> glob.glob('*.png')
['gnome-html.png', 'gnome-windows.png', 'gnome-set-time.png', ...]
>>> os.path.abspath('gnome-html.png')
'/usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-html.png'
```

With path, glob.glob return list of filename with directory part.

```
>>> glob.glob('/usr/share/pixmaps/*.png')
['/usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-html.png', '/usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-windows.png', '/usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-set-time.png',  ...]
```

---

```
import glob
import os

WD = r'E:\AA'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(WD, '*.jpg'))
with open('infiles.txt', 'w') as in_files:
    in_files.writelines(fn + '\n' for fn in files)
```

or

```
import glob
import os

WD = r'E:\AA'
os.chdir(WD)
files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
with open('infiles.txt', 'w') as in_files:
    in_files.writelines(os.path.join(WD, fn) + '\n' for fn in files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two line simple solution:

```
import os
filee = open('all_names.txt','w')
given_dir = 'the_dierctory'
[filee.write(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),given_dir,i)+'\n') for i in os.listdir(given_dir)]
```

where given_dir is the directory name. The output is a text file (all_names.txt) where each line in the file is the full path to all files and directories in the given_dir.

Comment: how can be to list all *.mp4 filenames from directory and subdirectory?